# Similar questions that appear below title need a little more refinement

Tags: feature-request

This is a great site and have been learning from it a lot.

Below is a small feature request that would be doing more good if added to this top site.

When we post a question, when the title is filled, we get some similar questions list.

we review it and them if desired is not found we fill in the body and then the tags.

When we fill in the tags - my suggestion/request is to show similar questions below title belonging to the programming language of the post only.

If i type in VB.Net tag, I get similar questions list with with Java and others too, this way I check only 2 or 3 and leave, but if only those relating to VB.net  or VB or similar language comes in, then I would check more than 3-5 since they would be understandable and similar name spacing.